# R xml2; transform nested xml file into data frame

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

I need to convert the nested xml file to a data frame using the xml2 package in R. My xml file looks like this:

```
File <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created with SDMX Converter v8.4.0-->
<message:CompactData xmlns:ns1="cc">
  <message:Header>
    <message:ID>EF123</message:ID>
    <message:Test>false</message:Test>
  </message:Header>
  <ns1:DataSet ID="IN_PR" dataflow="ET" action="Ifn">
  <ns1:Series FREQ="M" AREA="OO" ADJUST="W" IND="PD" ACT="P0789" PER="2006" TRANS="N" DEC="1" UNIT="0" MEAS="IX" FORMAT="P1M">
    <ns1:Obs TIME_PERIOD="2015-01" OBS_VALUE="5" STATUS="A" CONF="C"/>
    <ns1:Obs TIME_PERIOD="2015-02" OBS_VALUE="6" STATUS="A" CONF="C"/>
    <ns1:Obs TIME_PERIOD="2015-03" OBS_VALUE="8" STATUS="A" CONF="C"/>    
  </ns1:Series>
  <ns1:Series FREQ="M" AREA="OO" ADJUST="W" IND="PD" ACT="P0729" PER="2006" TRANS="N" DEC="1" UNIT="0" MEAS="IX" FORMAT="P1M">
    <ns1:Obs TIME_PERIOD="2015-01" OBS_VALUE="4" STATUS="A" CONF="F"/>
    <ns1:Obs TIME_PERIOD="2015-02" OBS_VALUE="1" STATUS="A" CONF="F"/>
    <ns1:Obs TIME_PERIOD="2015-03" OBS_VALUE="3" STATUS="A" CONF="F"/>   
  </ns1:Series>
 </ns1:DataSet>
</message:CompactData>'
```

After applying some simple commands I am able to concert the file into:

```
library(xml2)
library(restatapi)
library(dplyr)

sdmx_xml<-xml2::read_xml(File) ; smdx_xml
xml_leafs<-xml2::xml_find_all(sdmx_xml,".//ns1:Series") ; xml_leafs
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(xml_leafs, extract_data))) 

FREQ AREA ADJUST IND   ACT  PER TRANS DEC UNIT MEAS FORMAT TIME_PERIOD OBS_VALUE
1    M   OO      W  PD P0789 2006     N   1    0   IX    P1M     2015-01         5
2    M   OO      W  PD P0789 2006     N   1    0   IX    P1M     2015-02         6
3    M   OO      W  PD P0789 2006     N   1    0   IX    P1M     2015-03         8
4    M   OO      W  PD P0729 2006     N   1    0   IX    P1M     2015-01         4
5    M   OO      W  PD P0729 2006     N   1    0   IX    P1M     2015-02         1
6    M   OO      W  PD P0729 2006     N   1    0   IX    P1M     2015-03         3
```

I am missing the STATUS and CONF columns. The data frame should be like:

```
FREQ AREA ADJUST IND   ACT  PER TRANS DEC UNIT MEAS FORMAT TIME_PERIOD OBS_VALUE    STATUS  CONF
1    M   OO      W  PD P0789 2006     N   1    0   IX    P1M     2015-01         5      A   C
2    M   OO      W  PD P0789 2006     N   1    0   IX    P1M     2015-02         6      A   C
3    M   OO      W  PD P0789 2006     N   1    0   IX    P1M     2015-03         8      A   C
4    M   OO      W  PD P0729 2006     N   1    0   IX    P1M     2015-01         4      A   F
5    M   OO      W  PD P0729 2006     N   1    0   IX    P1M     2015-02         1      A   F
6    M   OO      W  PD P0729 2006     N   1    0   IX    P1M     2015-03         3      A   F
```

Do you know an way how can I add the missing columns.

Thank you.
John

Comment: By default, `restatapi::extract_data` only extracts the `TIME_PERIOD` and `OBS_VALUE` fields. If you set `keep_flags = TRUE`, it also searches for an `OBS_STATUS` field, but that does not fix your specific issue. If you do `extract_data <- edit(restatapi::extract_data)`, and edit the function line 20 to `cn <- c("TIME_PERIOD", "OBS_VALUE", "STATUS", "CONF")`, it works. This boils down to creating a new function with the name `extract_data`, that is a slightly edited version of `restatapi::extract_data`.

Comment: Dear Bas, Thank you very much. Your proposal solved the issue. Best regards, John